# Discord.py как редактировать Embed?

Tags: python, discord.py, edittext, edit

Подскажите, пожалуйста как редактировать Embed. Просто уже есть ответ на этот вопрос, но он редактировался один параметр короче:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dt(ctx, arg):
  tim = arg
  tim = int(tim)
  emb = discord.Embed(title = "Таймер", description = f"**{tim}**", colour = discord.Color.green())
  emb.set_image(url="https://i.gifer.com/152H.gif")
  msg = await ctx.send(embed = emb)
  while tim > -1:
    update_emb = Embed(title = "Таймер", description = f"**{tim}**", colour = discord.Color.green())
    update_emb2 = Embed(set_image url="https://i.gifer.com/152H.gif")
    tim = tim - 1
    print(tim)
    await msg.edit(embed=update_emb)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
  if tim <= 0:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await msg.delete()
```

Нужно чтобы он редактировал только один параметр это текст, переменную tim а все остальное оставлял как оно и есть, просто когда я щас редактирую текс Embed он удаляет все кроме этого текста

```
update_emb = Embed(title = "Таймер", description = f"**{tim}**", colour = discord.Color.green())
```

или

Когда он редактирует Embed он обновляет таймер: переменную tim, но удаляет gif, к сути нужно чтобы он редактировал два параметра или лучше чтобы он оставлял все как есть, но редактировал текст:

```
update_emb = Embed(title = "Таймер", description = f"**{tim}**", colour = discord.Color.green()) #1 параметр
update_emb2 = Embed(url="https://i.gifer.com/152H.gif") #2 параметр
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update_emb = discord.Embed(title = "Таймер", description = f"**{tim}**", colour = discord.Color.green())
update_emb.set_image(url="https://i.gifer.com/152H.gif") #2 параметр
```

Там где было **update_emb2 = Embed(url="https://i.gifer.com/152H.gif")**
надо было установить картинку для "**update_emb**"

По сути это была совсем другая переменная, которая не применялась при изменении сообщения

Comment: ответ правильный, но когда он обновляет Embed он обновляет не только текст ну и гифку и получается что каждую секунда он обновляет ее и она начинает проигрываться заново